# Bootstrap not working: Arduino MKR WiFi 1010 AP mode

Tags: mkr1010

I'm trying out the AP mode of the device, where it can serve as its own server. Most of the tutorials have been loading the html from the SD card. I can do the same, but the bootstrap of the website is not working. It just loads the basic version of the website. How can I fix this?

#### APMode.ino

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <WiFiNINA.h>
#define WEBHTM "SERVER/index.htm"
 
///////please enter your sensitive data in the Secret tab/arduino_secrets.h
char ssid[] = "MKRTEST";        // your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = "PASS";    // your network password (use for WPA, or use as key for WEP)
int keyIndex = 0;                // your network key Index number (needed only for WEP)

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
WiFiServer server(80);

File webFile;

void setup() 
{

    //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial);

    Serial.println("Access Point Web Server");


    // check for the WiFi module:
    if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_MODULE) {
    Serial.println("Communication with WiFi module failed!");
    // don't continue
    while (true);
    }

    if(!SD.begin(4))
    {
        Serial.println("SD card not found!");
        while(1);
    }

    if (!SD.exists(WEBHTM))
    {
        Serial.println("missing index.htm!");
        while(1);
    }
    
    String fv = WiFi.firmwareVersion();
    if (fv < WIFI_FIRMWARE_LATEST_VERSION) {
    Serial.println("Please upgrade the firmware");
    }

    // by default the local IP address of will be 192.168.4.1
    // you can override it with the following:
    // WiFi.config(IPAddress(10, 0, 0, 1));

    // print the network name (SSID);
    Serial.print("Creating access point named: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);

    // Create open network. Change this line if you want to create an WEP network:
    status = WiFi.beginAP(ssid);
    if (status != WL_AP_LISTENING) {
    Serial.println("Creating access point failed");
    // don't continue
    while (true);
    }

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);

    // start the web server on port 80
    server.begin();

    // you're connected now, so print out the status
    printWiFiStatus();
}


void loop() {
  // compare the previous status to the current status
  if (status != WiFi.status()) {
    // it has changed update the variable
    status = WiFi.status();

    if (status == WL_AP_CONNECTED) {
      // a device has connected to the AP
      Serial.println("Device connected to AP");
    } else {
      // a device has disconnected from the AP, and we are back in listening mode
      Serial.println("Device disconnected from AP");
    }
  }
  
  WiFiClient client = server.available();   // listen for incoming clients

  if (client) {                             // if you get a client,
    Serial.println("new client");           // print a message out the serial port
    String currentLine = "";                // make a String to hold incoming data from the client
    while (client.connected()) {            // loop while the client's connected
      if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,
        char c = client.read();             // read a byte, then
        Serial.write(c);                    // print it out the serial monitor
        if (c == '\n') {                    // if the byte is a newline character

          // if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
          // that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
          if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
            // HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
            // and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a blank line:
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-type:text/html");
            client.println();
            webFile = SD.open(WEBHTM);
            if (webFile)
            {
              while (webFile.available())
              {
                client.write(webFile.read());
              }
              webFile.close();
            }

            // The HTTP response ends with another blank line:
            client.println();
            // break out of the while loop:
            break;
          }
          else {      // if you got a newline, then clear currentLine:
            currentLine = "";
          }
        }
        else if (c != '\r') {    // if you got anything else but a carriage return character,
          currentLine += c;      // add it to the end of the currentLine
        }
        if (currentLine.endsWith("POST /enterCredentials")) {
        //   digitalWrite(led, HIGH);               // GET /H turns the LED on
        Serial.println("Hello there!");
        }
      }
    }
    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("client disconnected");
  }
}

void printWiFiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your WiFi shield's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print where to go in a browser:
  Serial.print("To see this page in action, open a browser to http://");
  Serial.println(ip);

}
```

#### index.htm

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>LPS Server</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="jumbotron text-center" style="margin-bottom:0">
  <h1>Low Power Sensor (LPS) Server</h1>
</div>

<div class="container" style="margin-top:30px" id="WifiDetails">
  <h3>Please enter needed Credentials</h3>
  <form action="/enterCredentials.htm" method="post"><label for="SSID">SSID:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="SSID"><label for="PASS">PASS:</label><input type="password" class="form-control" name="PASS"><label for="BROKER">Broker/Host:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="BROKER"><label for="DEVID">Device ID:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="DEVID"><input type="hidden" name="eof" value="#EOF"><br><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Submit">SUBMIT</button></form>  
</div>

<div class="jumbotron text-center" style="margin-bottom:0"><p>All Rights Reserved 2020</p></div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: so, what does this have to do with the arduino?

Comment: I'm using the Arduino MKR WiFi 1010. The library used is the "WiFiNINA" library which has an "AP mode" where the device can act as its own mini server.

Comment: how are you getting this file? ... https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Now I understand. I need to load the stylesheet from the file in the SD card. This won't work without internet connection. The only problem is how I can do that.

Comment: Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: take the css file, copy it to SD card and modify the path in html file

Comment: there is no reason for sending headers in a command line ... `client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");` .... just put the header lines at the top of `index.htm`

Comment: @jsotola, then it would not be a valid html file to debug it on PC